# Inject JavaScript for use on a site?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I'm completely new to this whole web aspect of iOS programming so bear with me :P. My goal is to grab a JavaScript file from a website, then "inject" that script so that I can use it to login on another site. I'm not sure if my practices are "the best" so if you notice something bad about them PLEASE tell me! :D

So, in my app, we start out with a view, where a user has two textboxes and a submit button. One textbox for a username, and one for a password. When the user hits submit, I want to page to load, throw the entered username and password in to the right places on the HTML page!

```
- (IBAction)signInTouched:(id)sender {

    if (userName.text.length > 0 && pass.text.length > 0)
    {
        NSString *theSite = @"www.thesite.com";

        NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:theSite];
        NSURLRequest *loginRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:theURL];

        [webView loadRequest:loginRequest]; // Webview is the web view :P

        NSURL *jsSite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.ThePlaceWithTheJS"];

        NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:jsSite encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];


        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

        NSString *userValue = userName.text;
        NSString *passValue = pass.text;
        NSString *javaFunction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"login(%@,%@)", userValue, passValue]; // login is the function in the javascript


        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaFunction];  

    }

    }
```

Then, here is the JS file:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function login(username,password){
    var usernameBox = document.getElementById("ctl00_plnMain_txtLogin");
    usernameBox.value = usernameBox.value + username;

    var passwordBox = document.getElementById("ctl00_plnMain_txtPassword");
    passwordBox.value = passwordBox.value + password;

}
</script>
```

So, the thing is I have no idea if I'm doing this all right, or how to get this to work properly.  Whenever I test it, the text isn't being loaded into the fields on the website. So it is obviously going wrong somewhere... but where?

Comment: Your objective sounds quite shady...

Comment: Why do you say that :P

Comment: Just a heads up coolcat, You don't have to beg people to help you on here, the entire purpose of everyone's browsing here is to solve your problem so it's inevitable that people will try to help. I don't know anything about ObjC so I can't really help you but I'm 900% sure someone will solve this for you.

Comment: Just to be sure, does your .js file actually containts <script> tag? If yes then this is your problem

Comment: It does in fact contain script tags :P. Is something wrong? I don't know JavaScript at all -- EDIT -- I removed them, nothing changed

Comment: I'll elaborate in answer, just a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

This call tries to execute your javascript

But, at this moment jsString containts `<script>` tag, which should not be used in .js file, tag used in HTML
So on evaluation of `<script>` comes the error

Just remove opening and closing tag in your .js file and it should be fine.

Also, this is not very good approach, if not really necessary, since you delay loading time of webview by loading script synchronous

You also should get your .js file in asynchronous mode and after receiving evaluate this file and your call to login function

Comment: It still doesn't call any of the functions D:

Comment: Well, there could be some other mistakes :)

Comment: Just try to alert-debug it. First of all replace this whole .js script with `function(){alert('inside .js file')}();` so you will know that you reached the point of file being loaded.

Comment: I changed the JS file to the code above and nothing happend; I'm guessing that's bad? :P -- Am I not injecting the JS file correctly?

Comment: So your JS is not executed. Actually it could be some  security layer preventing you from executing .js on any website and allowing only on local webview pages. Check the docs.

Comment: Do you think I could be calling the functions before I finished loading the page?

Comment: yeah, UIWebViewDelegate and - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView is a key

Comment: That ended up being the problem haha. Thanks.